# Basic solution, basic feasible solution, degeneracy

Tags: linear-programming

I have this matrix 
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}3&0&1&1&0\\2&1&0&0&0\\4&0&3&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$

and

$$b = \begin{bmatrix}5&3&6\end{bmatrix}$$

So this questions asks me to find if it's a basic solution, basic feasible solution and if its a degeneracy.

For the following: $$(a) \;  x = (0, 3, 0, 5, 6),$$

which i solved it and happens to be basic solution, bfs and degeneracy.

And the following I had to solve were

$$(b) \; x = (0, 3, 5, 0, −9), \qquad (f) \; x = (0, 3, 6, 0, 0).$$

my question is: $1)$ All my following question is the same as the x vector and to find the degeneracy it should be more than of the constraints that are active at $x$. So would all my following questions be degenerate since it has $n = 5$ and $m = 3$ which will give me $2$ all the time?

And I am not too sure how to find the basic feasible solution for the following questions.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: (a) and (b) are basic, (f) is *not* a solution.